# NoVNC integration in .net application

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How to integrate NoVNC in .net application for remote accessing?

Comment: did my answer help? If not, can you clarify your question as to what you are looking for more specifically?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on whether you want to integrate the noVNC client into a .net application or whether you want noVNC to be able to connect to a .net application in order to view it. I'm not sure why you would want to do the former since there are more efficient ways of adding a VNC client to a .net application. So I'll answer the second option (connecting to a .net application using noVNC).

noVNC is a VNC client; it implements the client part of the [RFB/VNC protocol](http://tigervnc.org/cgi-bin/rfbproto). The server that noVNC connects to must implement the server part of the RFB/VNC protocol. The simplest option is to run a separate VNC server that can serve a single Window (the application could launch the VNC server under it's control). Otherwise you have to implement all the VNC/RFB semantics in the application itself:

- VNC authentication
- encoding negotiation
- keep track of the visual state of the application over time
- do something with client mouse state and keyboard state information
- answer client FBU (frame buffer update) requests by calculating the rectangles inside the requested area that have changed since the last time the client requested that area. Marshal those rectangles into the best encoding supported by both client and server.
- etc

Also a web browser cannot initiate raw TCP socket connections, only WebSocket connections. In addition to the WebSockets handshake and framing, WebSockets only current permits UTF-8 encoded payloads. To get around these limitations, noVNC uses [websockify](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify) to translate between raw TCP sockets and WebSockets. To get around the WebSockets UTF-8 limitation, websockify base64 encodes/decodes all traffic to/from the browser. The functionality of websockify could be implemented along with the VNC server functionality. In fact, [this fork of libvncserver](https://github.com/kanaka/libvncserver) has WebSockets (and base64 encoding) support builtin (i.e. noVNC can connect directly to it without websockify).

If you still want to try to implement VNC/RFB and WebSockets support in you .net application, then you might be able to use [this C# code](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/c_sharp_web_socket_server.aspx?msg=3364691) as a reference for the WebSockets functionality.